# Trying to print numbers from list, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read numbers from a text file (20 numbers) and print odd numbers and multiples of 7

```
numbers = open('numbers' , 'r')

nums=[]
cnt=1

while cnt<20:
    nums.append(numbers.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    cnt += 1

print nums

oddNumbers = []
multiplesOf7 = []

for x in nums:
    num = int(nums[x])
    if num%2 > 0 :
        oddNumbers.append(num)
    elif num%7 > 0 :
        multiplesOf7.append(num)

print('Odd numbers: ' , oddNumbers)
print('Multiples of 7: ' , multiplesOf7)
```

I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last): ['21', '26', '27', '28', '7', '14',
>   '36', '90', '85', '40', '60', '50', '55', '45', '78', '24', '63',
>   '75', '12']   File
>   "C:/Users/y0us3f/PycharmProjects/Slimanov/oddmultiples.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       num = int(nums[x]) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates over members of `nums`, so `x` is not an integer. You just need `num = int(x)`.

Comment: The error clearly mentions that the values in the list are text, not integers. So, first you have to convert it to integers, then perform the operation on it.

Answer (score 2):

You're already iterating over values inside nums. Don't look up the value from nums again:

```
# nums = ['21', '26', '27', '28', '7', '14', '36', '90', '85', '40', '60', '50', '55', '45', '78', '24', '63', '75', '12']
for x in nums:
    # x is '21', '26', etc.
    num = int(x)
    ...
```

You're getting an exception because you're trying to look up a value from nums using a string index: `nums['21']`, but in this case you don't even need to, as you already have the value of '21' stored in x.

Comment: A small addition: If you add `int()` to  the list creation you won't have to deal with strings anymore and can replace all the 'nums' inside your loop with references to x. That's assuming your file contains only integers.
`nums.append(int(numbers.readline().rstrip('\n'))))`